# With Xcode 5 and Asset Catalog, are we still required to include the CFBundleIcons key in Info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios7, xcode5

Finally I gut the Asset Catalog of Xcode 5 working for the app icons.

The app supports iOS 6 and up.
The remaining puzzle piece is: Is it still necessary to include a CFBundleIcons key? And do the file names matter?

[Apple put together this document which talks about including CFBundleIcons key](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html). I am confused because I don't see what the advantage of Asset Catalog is then.

---

Some tips for my fellow app developers:

**Some icons in the App Icon Asset Catalog have the same size. You can reuse icons. By default, Xcode will copy them.** When you drag an icon from Finder to the second placeholder, Xcode will create a heavy copy of your icon. It adds a `-1` to the name. When you want to reuse an icon for two placeholders, right-click your "AppIcon" Asset Catalog item in the left under the "Images.xcassets" tab, and select "Show in Finder". You will see a folder named `AppIcon.appiconset` which contains a `Contents.json` file. Open this file in a text editor (like Sublime Text or Smultron), search for the file name of the duplicated icon, and rename the entry to match the name of the original. Then delete the duplicated icon.

**To reveal the Asset Catalog**, click on your project file at the top of the Project Navigator. Select your target. Scroll down to "App Icons" section. Click the arrow to the right.

**To remove the gloss effect added by iOS**, select your "AppIcon" asset catalog on the left. Then reveal the inspector. Click on the upper right icon in Xcode to show the right panel. Then click on the rightmost icon to see the properties inspector. Check "iOS icon is pre-rendered".

**The fat 512x512 and 1024x1024 iTunesArtwork files without extension** are only required for enterprise apps which are made for internal Ad Hoc distribution. App Store apps don't need this.

Comment: Is the any way to get rid of the gloss effect in iTunesArtwork in Ad-Hoc Distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need put CFBundleIcons in info.plist again. Xcode automatically add this to pist file. Just create Asset Catalog, set up project and you can upload it.

For my new Apps I just setup Asset Catalog and upload to AppStore well.

Comment: In my case Xcode does not add an CFBundleIcons key to Info.plist.

Comment: The entries are automatically added to the Info.plist file within the built app bundle, not necessarily to the one in your Xcode project.